# About the integral of $\frac{x}{e^{x^2}+1}$

Tags: integration

Hi I am trying to find the integral $\int \frac{x}{e^{x^2} +1}\,dx$. The only techniques I know of so far are u-sub, integration by parts, and inspection. Can this be solved by these methods?

Like when I stare at this I don't see integration by parts helping because it wouldn't make it simpler by choosing that e value as either a u or dv. I was only able to get so far with u-sub till I got stuck.

Comment: try using the u-sub : $u = x^2$

Comment: We don't usually integrate equations, but functions or differential forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $u=x^2$.

Then $du = 2x \,dx$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle \int \frac{x}{e^{x^2}+1}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{e^{(x^2)}+1}(2x\,dx)=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{e^u+1}\,du=\frac{1}{2}\int \left(1-\frac{e^u}{1+e^u}\right)\,du=$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}(u-\ln(1+e^u)+C)=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(1+e^{x^2}\right)+C}$

Comment: Missing factor $2$.

Comment: Thank you. Edited @YvesDaoust

Comment: wait, one second

Comment: Hem, applied the wrong way...

Comment: sorry sorry wait another second i know its supposed to be one half

Comment: ALRIGHT HAHA got it this time! @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**:

$$\frac x{e^{x^2}+1}=\frac{xe^{-x^2}}{1+e^{-x^2}}.$$

A substitution is now possible.

Comment: All too easy (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use the substitution
$$
u=e^{x^2}+1 \quad \rightarrow \quad xdx=\frac{1}{2}\frac{du}{e^{x^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{du}{u-1 }
$$

than use partial fraction decomposition.